# Skip struts validation when a field is disabled?

Tags: validation, struts, disabled-control

### I have UI page (JSP file)which is having fields like as Follows:

### Eno   :

### Ename :

### Estatus :  Employee/Contractor dropdown box (having 2 values)

### Ebonus :  (This field will show only Estatus value is 'Employee', It will disabled when Estatus value is 'Contractor' )

I have struts validation for above form. But, the problem is when ever I choose 'contractor' in Estatus, then the Ebonus field will be disabled. So, I want to skip te validation for that particular time only.

Please any one can suggest a good idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Saying you have validation for the form, I assume you are talking about validate() method from the action class. If you are validating the form at the jsp you shouldn't do this.

When you choose 'Contractor...' in 'Estatus' field you could do something like this to skip Ebonus field validation.

Action class that has this form:

```
public class YouClassAction extends ActionSupport implements Validateable {

...

public void validate() {     
    if ( Eno.length() == 0 ) {  
        addFieldError( "Eno", "Eno is required." );         
    }
    ... 

    if ( Estatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Employee") ) {  
        //VALIDATE HERE Ebonus field         
    }    
    ...   
}
}
```

Check this for more details about validating a struts 2 form: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/form-validation.html

Comment: Hi exoddus, Thanks for your reply. Actually I am using validation.xml. I want to skip one particular validation in side the validation.xml, example,                                        <field property="ebonus" depends="float">
 <arg0 key="prompt.ebonus"/>
</field>.                                                                        Thanks

Comment: Then I recomend you (based on my knwoledge) validate this field with validate() method from your class (or combine xml validation with validate() method). There you could do semantic validation with multiple fields.
You could also try with short-circuit param form field-validator element. This param stop the rest of validations if that one doesn't pass, but this param is actually for multiple validations on the SAME field, or I think so...

Comment: Hey, Thank you.I will try and let you know the result.Thank you